# Recursively read integers into an array of exactly the right size using C

Tags: c, file-io, recursion

This insertnext function attempts to place integers from its input file into an array of exactly the right size, with the limitation that the file is to be read only once.  This recursive function keeps track of the number of integers read, allocates memory for their array in the base case (when the file has no more integers), and then writes the integers into the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insertnext(FILE *fp, int *a, long i) {
    int cur;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &cur);

    if (feof(fp))            // BASE CASE: Allocate Memory
        a = (int *) malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    else {
        insertnext(fp, a, i+1);  // GENERAL CASE's RECURSIVE CALL
        a[i] = cur;              // Executes after the base case does
    }
}

int main() {
    int *a;
    FILE *fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    insertnext(fp, a, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The program does execute to the function's base case and allocates the correct amount of memory for the integer array a.  However, upon the first execution of the line a[i] = cur, the program outputs "Segmentation fault (core dumped)."  It seems to me that the integer pointer a no longer points to the allocated memory after completing the base case's function call, though I don't see why that would happen.

Do you have any thoughts on what the problem could be?

Comment: Note, that with that approach, all the integers are put onto the stack first, before they are copied into the dynamic array. Depending on the size of the input file you'll have a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a really helpful observation.

Answer (score 2):

For the newly allocated array pointer to propagate back up the call stack, you need to pass it by pointer (i.e. use `int**`):

```
void insertnext(FILE *fp, int **a, long i) {
    //...
    if (feof(fp))            // BASE CASE: Allocate Memory
        *a = (int *) malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    else {
        insertnext(fp, a, i+1);  // GENERAL CASE's RECURSIVE CALL
        (*a)[i] = cur;              // Executes after the base case does
    }
}

int main() {
    int *a;
    //...
    insertnext(fp, &a, 0);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Also, this code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

malloc return value (pointer in memory area) is lost after the base case is lost.
You can try to use the following function declaration:

```
void insertnext(FILE *fp, int **a, long i)
```

and modify the function code accordingly.